# how to fix Can’t make "Variable" into type integer

Tags: safari, applescript

I'm attempting to make a script to auto open safari, then login to my account from there but when I tell system events to keystroke my login variable I get an error

I haven't tried much since I'm a newbie to AppleScript but what I have found is that whether I try to keystroke my variable or I directly type my string text both give the same error

```
open location "https://www.edutyping.com/student/login"
set LoginUSER to "Placeholder"
tell "System Events"
    keystroke LoginUSER
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `tell` command is targeting the **string** (text) `"System Events"`.  A string cannot do an awful lot except be a string, and it definitely doesn't know how to send key strokes.  However, you can use this string with an *object specifier*, such as `application`, that will point AppleScript to a specific *object* of the specific type (e.g. `application`) with a specific name (the string), which--assuming the object exists, etc.--you can `tell` to do all sorts of stuff:

```
set LoginUSER to "Placeholder"
open location "https://www.edutyping.com/student/login"

tell application "System Events" --> Ahhh....!
    keystroke LoginUSER
end tell
```

Here, `application "System Events"` (which can also be written as `the application named "System Events"`) is directing AppleScript to an application on your machine with the name "System Events".  Since AppleScript is, thankfully, very familiar with pretty much every application on your machine, and knows all their names, this makes a lot more sense to it when you then want to `tell` it to do stuff.  Provided the stuff you tell it to do is stuff it understands, it will--for the most part--go ahead and do that.

Now... *Obviously*, if you sent **me** an email commanding I do the following:

```
open location "https://www.edutyping.com/student/login"
keystroke "<your name and password>"
```

I would, of course, open that location and I would, of course, **wait for the page to load first** before I then keystroked my way into your student account, and then I'd probably command myself to do whatever I damn well please now that I'm logged in to your student account.

AppleScript, however, probably *won't* realise you would want it to wait for the page to load, so it will just start typing out what you tell it to.  (Oh, and, by the way, AppleScript is *really-frickin-quick-at-typing*.  I can average maybe 120-140 words per minute on a good day.  AppleScript can probably do 140 words per second.)

So, if it looks like AppleScript did the first bit but not the rest, it's actually because it did everything without procrastinating.  But you can force it to wait for a few seconds using the `delay` command:

```
set LoginUSER to "Placeholder"
open location "https://www.edutyping.com/student/login"
delay 7.18340739
tell application "System Events" to keystroke LoginUSER
```

I have no idea how long that webpage will take to load on your system, so you can change that number to `pi` or whatever.  There are slightly better methods to get AppleScript to space out the timing of those two commands rather than using a fixed `delay` (which is just guessing how long a page *might* take to load), but that's for another day.